# pytest run markers via configuration file

Tags: python, pytest

I am running some functional tests using pytest for command line testing.
I have my tests in a yml file which is used for test configuration.
I want to provide some markers in my yml file which can be used by pytest instead of using the decorator approach inside the test file.

e.g

```
---
test_name: xyz
test_type: smoke
command: hello --help
expected: hello world
assertions:
  - testResult.actual_command_returnCode == 0
  - len(testResult.expected_value_result) != 0
  - testResult.expected_value_result[0] == testResult.actual_command_output
```

Is there a way i can specify markers in my yml file and pytest can used the same for understanding which specific tests it needs to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

py.test does not read yaml files, you will have to write your own code that does that and adds markers to your test functions. You can do that with a hook function placed in your `conftest.py` file. Here is an example that places a marker `smoke` on a test named `test_a`:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    for i in items:
        if i.name == "test_a":
            i.add_marker("smoke")
```

This function (if present in `conftest.py`) is automatically called by py.test once, right after it collects a list of tests from your directory and before any tests are actually run. You can modify the list `items` as you wish.

(NOTE my example looks only at the test name, so it will match a function named `test_a` in any test file; you may need a different way of selecting the actual test to which to apply the marker, e.g., compare the value of `i.nodeid`, which is a string like `path/file.py::function_name`.)

This is only an example, you should replace the code with something that reads your yaml file and decides which markers to add to what tests, depending on what it finds in that file.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

I created a hook in my conftest.py file as follows

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config,items):
  with open("C:\Users\xyz\mno\cli_automation\test_configuration\project\test_command.yml", 'r') as stream:
    data_loaded = yaml.load(stream)
    for i in items:
        if i.name == data_loaded.get("test_name"):
            i.add_marker(data_loaded.get("test_type"))
            pytest_runtest_call(i)
```

I am getting an attribute error when i do the pytest_runtest_call(i) as 
    `AttributeError: 'Function' object has no attribute '_evalxfail'`. Checked in the source code of [https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/_modules/_pytest/skipping.html] , its failing at line 102 at `evalxfail = item._evalxfail` not sure why